# Android sharing internal and external storage files

Tags: android

I have been searching for hours. I want to share a file from my internal storage with file provider. I get the correct content://Uri and gave the permissions. But I can not share it to the other apps to open that file.

On the other hand I can share from external storage.

Please help me

Here what I did:

```
File file = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)+File.separator+"example.pdf");
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file); // This way I can open.



File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir()+File.separator+"example.pdf");
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file); // now I can not open it
```

The intent of opening application:

```
public void openfile(Uri fileUri)
{
    String mimeType = getMimeType(fileUri); // returns correct mime type
    File imagePath = new File(mContext.getFilesDir().toString(),"data/data/com.kryptos.ctech.kryptos/files");
    File newFile = new File(imagePath,fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName(),newFile);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
    shareIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);
    //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
}
```

Comment: "But I can not share it to the other apps to open that file" -- what does this mean? What are your specific symptoms? The `File` that you are passing to `getUriForFile()` seems to be for a location in `getCacheDir()`, while your first code snippet does not use `getCacheDir()`. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that makes a PDF available via `FileProvider` for use with `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: It means I can not make other apps open the file. The receiver application pops up. But it says" this file can not be opened". Or it says "do not have permission to access." Secondly I will edit that part.